# Kotlin, define object with class type that extends generic

Tags: generics, kotlin

I've got MVP realization that I try to convert in Kotlin, but I am stuck with generics - I failed in instantiating object with unknown type that extends parent presenter class. I've got interface for presenters:

```
interface BasePresenter {
    fun attachView(view: View)
    fun detachView(view: View)
...}
```

And some basic code for fragment that will have presenter. In java it works this way:

```
abstract public class BaseFragmentWithPresenter<P extends BasePresenter> extends BaseFragment {
    @Inject
    protected P presenter;
```

As you can see, in this parent class I use Dagger 2 for presenter injection, and I also predefine some logic here:

```
public void onViewCreated(...) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    presenter.attachView(this);
}
```

How to do this in Kotlin? I read about in\out technics but still failed.

Comment: Could you please clarify where exactly do you have the issue? Code should be like this: `abstract class BaseFragmentWithPresenter<P:  BasePresenter>: BaseFragment() {

    lateinit var p: P
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
abstract class BaseFragmentWithPresenter<P : BasePresenter> : BaseFragment() {
    protected abstract val presenter: P
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that Kotlin is much more heavy with generics rather than Java.
I came across with this solution:

```
abstract class BaseFragmentWithPresenter<V : BaseView, P : BasePresenter<V>> : BaseFragment() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    presenter.attachView(this as V)
}
```